# php mysqli affected rows returns wrong result after delete statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a function to delete a row from my table and I like to return true if the row existed before. I use the following function achieve that:

```
$mysqli = $this->mysqli;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM active_clients WHERE token LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows < 1){
    $stmt->close();
    return false;
}
$stmt->close();
return true;
```

It also worked propperly on my local host but when I moved to live server it doesn't return the correct result. affected_rows returns always 0 but the row is deleted as it should be. How can it be? Could there be a problem with php-version? I run locally 5.4 and on live server 5.3... Or ist it also possible that it has something to do with database or server configuration?

Comment: Why not use `WHERE token = ?` Using LIKE may not be what you want here, as it could have unwanted/unexpected results.

Comment: Check to make sure that affected_rows is returning the right number first:
    `printf("Affected rows: %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);`

Comment: I just request the first strings of the token using "blablabla%" as string to be tested. That's why I use the LIKE statement. $stmt->affected_rows returns exactly 0

Comment: @abimelex Looking back at both my answer and your question I see that we missed the `$this->mysqli` on `prepare()` also the comparison should be `if($stmt->affected_rows < 0)` since `if($stmt->affected_rows < 1)` means less than one row is affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mysqli = $this->mysqli;

$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM active_clients WHERE token LIKE ?");
if(!$stmt){
    die('prepare() failed: ' . $mysqli->error);
}else{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $token);

    if($stmt->execute()){
       $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->affected_rows < 0){
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }else{
            $stmt->close();
            return true;    
        }
    }else{
        die('execute() failed: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }


}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, is it necessary to put it on connection object? Because on local it does work...

Comment: @abimelex have you tried to print it `printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);`

Comment: In the php.net example it's also on the $stmt : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: @abimelex Ok I expanded on my answer please check. if prepare ever returns false then it wouldnt work

Comment: @abimelex I found someone with your issue http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/284557-get-affected-rows-after-delete-mysql/ do you have the percent sign in your token value

Comment: I have no % in my token. In data base there are sha512 generated tokens stored which I assume have no % in it. I just use the % as wildcard suffix in my query to check just for the first 16 characters from the token. I will try to run my code on another webserver since this hoster has also some other problems.

Comment: @abimelex its not clear to me why you prefer to use LIKE over checking the field itself. But you need the percent at least one. `$stmt->bind_param('s', '%'.$token.'%');` also you can always check if the row existed with a select before deleting

Comment: @abimelex I found the issue, you need to store the result `$stmt->store_result();` see my edit

Comment: that didn't fixed it too. Thanks for your help, but I guess it's some hoster issue.

Comment: @abimelex would you like me to add a bounty to this question?

Comment: No problem if you like.

Comment: Your answer served me well today @meda Cheers and Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks a lot fred, Merry Christmas to you and your family, God bless you with many more !

Comment: @meda You're welcome, and thank you. God bless you and your family too, *cheers!*

Answer (score -1):

> If the last query was a DELETE query with no WHERE clause, all of the records will have been deleted from the table but this function will return zero with MySQL versions prior to 4.1.2.

Check your Mysql version.

Resource: http://php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: The OP is using `mysqli_*` not `mysql_*` functions.